# D3: improving my shape-text linkup

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization

This is a technique/optimization question.  Using a number of sources in SA and bl.ocks I've been able to get a horizontal legend w/rotated text, as shown here.  I've clipped it for proprietary reasons.

[image: horizontal legend]

Here is the code I used:

```
var svg_legend = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width+margin.left)
    .attr("height", 180)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

rects=svg_legend.selectAll("rect")
.data(coldomain)
.enter().append("rect")
.attr("height", 15)
.attr("x", function(d, i) { return (i+1)*((width-margin.left)/coldomain.length); })
.attr("width", 15)
.style("fill", color);    

text = svg_legend.selectAll("text")
    .data(coldomain)
  .enter().append("text")
    .text(function(d){return d})
    .style("fill", 'black')
    .attr("y", 60)
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .style("font-size", "12px") 
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(" + (i)*((width-margin.left)/coldomain.length)+",0) rotate(-65," + 0+"," + 0+") "; })
```

As so this works, but it seems like I one should be able to do the rectangles and text in one pass, so that you wouldn't have to worry about getting them to line up, b/c the text would somehow be dynamically synched with the rectangles.  Is there a better way to achieve the above?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach may be to create groups under the main group, bind the data to this groups, translate them and then append rectangles and text to each group. The outline of this strategy is:

```
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg'),
    grp = svg.append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

// Compute the actual translation and replace the zeros
var groups = grp.selectAll('g')
  .data(coldomain)
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', function(d) { return 'translate(0, 0)'; });

// The rectangles are now relative to the parent group
groups.append('rect')
  .attr('x',   0)
  .attr('y', -10)
  .attr('width', 10)
  .attr('height', 10);

// The text position is now relative to the parent group 
groups.append('text')
  .attr('x', 0)
  .attr('y', 10)
  .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
```

The data items binded to the groups are passed to their children elements, in this case, the `rect` and `text` elements.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll try it.  MB recommended something very like this on a related topic, but I couldn't picture how it might be done.  Let's assume its works and accept this as the answer :).

Comment: I'm adding the article so the question and answer are more complete: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/